# pass parameter function Node.js from one js to another

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, function, express

I am trying to pass function response from one Node.js script to another

Here is what I am trying.
Index.js

```
var express = require('express');

require('./meter');

var app = express();

app.get('/',function(req,res){
    return;                    //hi function from another file
})

app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on 3000 port')
```

meter.js

```
module.exports = {

    hi: function(req, res) {
        return res.status(200).json({"message" : "Hello V1"});
    }
};
```

does require function only will do the job?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Yes. But you will have to export `hi` in `meter.js` and you'll have to use it similar to what you've done for express.

Comment: Thanks @PratikGaikwad. But I get what you are saying but don't know how to do that. Please can you write little code in Answer

Comment: please see the answer posted by Nir Levy below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you use require, you should assign it to a variable, and then you can use it in your code:

```
var express = require('express');
var meter = require('./meter');  // meter will be an object you can use later on
var app = express();

app.get('/',meter.hi); // you actually don't need another annonimous function, can use hi directly as the callback

app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on 3000 port')
```

Comment: Thanks @Nir Levy. Worked perfectly. :)

Answer (score 2):

The answer by Nir Levy is correct but I'll try to give you a little more context on what's going on.

```
var express = require('express');
// Import the meter export and assign it a variable for reuse.
var meter = require('./meter');
var app = express();
app.listen(3000);
console.log('listening on 3000 port')
```

As per Nir's answer, you'll just use `meter.hi` for handling get requests to `/`

```
app.get('/', meter.hi);
```

What exactly is happening here is JavaScript passes all the arguments to the `meter.hi` method. In case of express there will be 3 arguments here - `request`, `response` and `next` passed in that order.

In the module `meter` you are just using request and response alone, which is fine, but if there's any other processing required or arguments for `meter.hi` needs to vary you might want to follow the following practise.

```
app.get('/', function( req, res ) {
  // You can process the request here.
  // Eg. authentication
  meter.hi(req, res);
});
```

Where you have more control over the arguments being passed to your modules.